# Forcing https using modrewrite in apache conf losing basic authentication credentials

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

I'm trying to force https with a system that uses basic authentication in the URL but when I add the following lines to the apache configuration files:

```
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R]
```

the results are 302 errors.

If someone types as the URL:
    http://username:password@example.com/api_name.php
Based on the access log, I think the redirect is going to:
    https:example.com/api_name.php

What I want is it to redirect to:
    https://username:password@example.com/api_name.php

But I also want:
    http://example.com/api_name.php
to correctly redirect to:
    https://example.com/api_name.php
and not:
    http://:@example.com/api_name.php

URL's without credentials contained within the string are working fine and redirect correctly.

How would I make this work?

Comment: _"the results are 302 errors"_ - there is no such thing, 302 is not an _error_ code, that is simply the redirect. _"Based on the access log, I think the redirect is going to: https:example.com/api_name.php"_ - of course; after all that is what you _said_ it should redirect to. The credentials are not really passed to the server "in" the URL - that is just a construct clients use, they automatically translate that into the request header for basic auth. On top of that, I am not sure that you even have access to the password at that level ...

Comment: ... there's the env variable REMOTE_USER listed in the docs for RewriteCond, but no matching one for the password. And I might even question whether it makes sense to rewrite in that way. You'd be putting sensitive credentials _into_ a URL that gets send over the net "unprotected" (since we are still responding to the first _HTTP_ request here) that were not part of the initially requested URL (see above, client-side construct) ... so I'd hardly call that an _increase_ in security.

Comment: re: 'increased security', the broken calls are internal soap request behind a firewall, but the server has some exposed apis/ports to the DMZ.  The DMZ api's require a username/password page, hence reason to force https.

_Maybe I'm asking the wrong question:_
**How do I get the "force https" mod-rewrite script pass through basic authentication credentials via the standard HTTP "Authorization" header?**

Comment: They only way to pass them _through_ would be by proxying the request - which would not win you much, because then you would hand back the result of that request made by proxy to the original client over the insecure HTTP connection again. You want the client to repeat the request, while "upgrading" the protocol - so the client is the one who has to send the credentials again. Aren't you maybe trying to saddle this horse from the wrong end? If improving security is the objective, then I would rather reject insecure requests. Let the consumers of this API update the configuration on their end.